# Clojure: update-in, but with wildcards and path tracking

Tags: dictionary, clojure, tree

I'm trying to update values in a structure consisting of nested maps and sequences, but `update-in` won't work because I want to allow wildcards. My manual approach led me to ugly, big, nested `for` and `into {}` calls. I ended up making a function that takes the structure, a selector-like sequence, and an update function.

```lisp
(defn update-each-in
  ([o [head & tail :as path] f]
   (update-each-in o path f []))
  ([o [head & tail :as path] f current-path]
   (cond
     (empty? path) (f o current-path)
     (identical? * head)
       (cond
         (map? o)
           (into {} (for [[k v] o]
             [k (update-each-in v tail f (conj current-path k))]))
         :else (for [[i v] (map-indexed vector o)]
           (update-each-in v tail f (conj current-path i))))
     :else (assoc o head
       (update-each-in (get o head) tail f (conj current-path head))))))
```

This allows me to simplify my updates to the following

```lisp
(def sample {"TR" [{:geometry {:ID12 {:buffer 22}}}
                   {:geometry {:ID13 {:buffer 33}
                               :ID14 {:buffer 55}}}
                   {:geometry {:ID13 {:buffer 44}}}]
             "BR" [{:geometry {:ID13 {:buffer 22}
                               :ID18 {:buffer 11}}}
                   {:geometry {:ID13 {:buffer 33}}}
                   {:geometry {:ID13 {:buffer 44}}}]})

(update-each-in sample [* * :geometry * :buffer]
  (fn [buf path] (inc buf)))
```

Obviously this has a stack overflow problem with deeply nested structures; although I'm far from hitting that one, it'd be nice to have a robust solution. Can anyone suggest a simpler/faster/more elegant solution? Could this be done with reducers/transducers?

**UPDATE** It's a requirement that the updating function also gets the full path to the value it's updating.

Comment: Can you provide sample expected output to your question?

Comment: @Symfrog You can eval the entire example, it will give you the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

`update-in` has exactly the same signature as the function you created, and it does almost exactly the same thing. There are two differences: it doesn't allow wildcards in the "path," and it doesn't pass intermediary paths to the update function.

**Adding wildcards to `update-in`**

I've adapted this from the [source code for update-in](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5687).

```
(defn update-in-*
    [m [k & ks] f & args]
        (if (identical? k *)
            (let [idx (if (map? m) (keys m) (range (count m)))]
                (if ks
                    (reduce #(assoc % %2 (apply update-in-* (get % %2) ks f args))
                            m
                            idx)
                    (reduce #(assoc % %2 (apply f (get % %2) args))
                            m
                            idx)))
            (if ks
                (assoc m k (apply update-in-* (get m k) ks f args))
                (assoc m k (apply f (get m k) args)))))
```

Now these two lines produce the same result:

```
(update-in-* sample [* * :geometry * :buffer] (fn [buf] (inc buf)))
(update-each-in sample [* * :geometry * :buffer] (fn [buf path] (inc buf)))
```

The change I made to `update-in` is just by branching on a check for the wildcard. If the wildcard is encountered, then every child-node at that level must be modified. I used `reduce` to keep the cumulative updates to the collection.

Also, another remark, in the interests of robustness: I'd try to use something other than `*` for the wildcard. It could possibly occur as the key in a map.

**Adding path-tracking to `update-in`**

If it is required that the updating function receive the full path, then I would just modify `update-in` one more time. The function signature changes and  `(conj p k)` gets added, but that's about it.

```
(defn update-in-*
    [m ks f & args] (apply update-in-*-with-path [] m ks f args))

(defn- update-in-*-with-path
    [p m [k & ks] f & args]
        (if (identical? k *)
            (let [idx (if (map? m) (keys m) (range (count m)))]
                (if ks
                    (reduce #(assoc % %2 (apply update-in-*-with-path (conj p k) (get % %2) ks f args))
                            m
                            idx)
                    (reduce #(assoc % %2 (apply f (conj p k) (get % %2) args))
                            m
                            idx)))
            (if ks
                (assoc m k (apply update-in-*-with-path (conj p k) (get m k) ks f args))
                (assoc m k (apply f (conj p k) (get m k) args)))))
```

Now these two lines produce the same result:

```
(update-in-* sample [* * :geometry * :buffer] (fn [path val] (inc val)))
(update-each-in sample [* * :geometry * :buffer] (fn [buf path] (inc buf)))
```

Is this better than your original solution? I don't know. I like it because it is modeled after `update-in`, and other people have probably put more careful thought into `update-in` than I care to myself.

Comment: Very nice try, it didn't occur to me at all to look at `update-in`'s source code. However. This does not work if any of the nested structures is not `IAssociative`, ie. the input data is usually a product of functions producing lazy sequences, not some hand coded `sample` consisting of just maps and vectors. My original version does work because it uses `for` form. It actually taught me that `core`'s `update-in` doesn't work with lazy sequences.

Comment: Actually mine would break too if the last element in `path` would be an integer index into a lazy seq. because it's using `assoc` too.

Comment: @skrat Then you could continue adapting by writing your own assoc that works for all sequences, and by using get/nth based on whether you're looking at a map, etc. etc. I don't know your use-case, but you might want to reconsider your choice of data structure. See [these Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1859471/2472391).